# How to copy/move my dead Windows 8.1 user profile to a new Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows, move, user-profile

I have a dead windows 8.1 which does not boot. I want to transfer all the userprofile of user a to the new Win 10 installation.
I know that I can copy the [partition]\Users\a folder to the new windows 10 in the same directory, but what about registry hives? Should I edit anything in the registry of the  dead user account to make it compatible to the new win 10 ? Because I already :
1. created a user named: a in the new win 10 using computer management
2. renamed c:\users\a -> c:\users\a_DontUse
3. copied old user a folder to c:\users\a
4. tried to login with that user but couldn't! Windows just signs out! and it does not log in to that user account!

How can I fix this? Is there any reg key in that NTuser.dat file in the user account of old user that I have to change something in it?